# how to fix "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1"

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start

Every time I run "npm install" I get this:

```
"npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! CodingPhase-StarterKit@1.0.0 watch: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the CodingPhase-StarterKit@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jcdev/.npm/_logs/2018-12-28T04_06_04_816Z-debug.log"
```

I've tried to re-install npm, update it, force the installation, and I've read most of the problems on Stack Overflow related to npm issues and I still can't fix my problem.I'm relatively new to the community, thank you in advance